# Failed to start docker application container engine

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using docker on ubuntu 18.04 LTS to create mongoDB shards for one of my projects, all was working fine but then lately my machines experienced an abnormal shutdown and after that I'm unable to start my docker service. below are the logs which I was able to get from the system.

**sudo systemctl status docker.service**:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-11-16 17:14:13 PKT; 9s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 10661 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 10661 (code=exited, status=2)

Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

**sudo journalctl -xe:**

```
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Nov 16 17:14:13 mongodb-linux systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
Nov 16 17:17:01 mongodb-linux CRON[10791]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 16 17:17:01 mongodb-linux CRON[10792]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 16 17:17:01 mongodb-linux CRON[10791]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 16 17:17:37 mongodb-linux sudo[10800]: naqiazam : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Nov 16 17:17:37 mongodb-linux sudo[10800]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

I'm not able to understand the problem kindly help me through this I'm a beginner with docker

Comment: The only error message you've provided indicates the service failed too many times before. You need to find and post the previous error that triggered the rate limit.

Comment: @BMitch how am i supposed to do that?